# Vue.js component call a method inside data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'd like to assign component methods to data variables, see the example code below. Sadly it does not work, what is the correct way?

```html
<li v-for="item in items" @click="item.action">
    {{ item.title }}
</li>
```

```js
export default {
    data: () => ({
        items: [
            { title: "One", action: this.funcOne },
            { title: "Two", action: this.funcTwo },
        ]
    }),
    methods: {
        funcOne() {
            alert("Hi")
        },
        funcTwo() {
            alert("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass the vue instance (`this`) as parameter to the data function `data: (vm) =>` then use it `action: vm.funcOne`

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
      data: (vm) => ({ // vm the component instance this
        items: [
            { title: "One", action: vm.funcOne},
            { title: "Two", action: vm.funcTwo },
        ]
    }),
    methods: {
        funcOne() {
            alert("Hi")
        },
        funcTwo() {
            alert("Hello")
        }
    }
  })
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
<li v-for="item in items" @click="item.action">
    {{ item.title }}
</li>
</div>
```